# SQL cross apply and unpivot function

Tags: sql-server, unpivot, cross-apply

I have a some data regarding the customer service calls and now I want to create a sankey chart with the data in power bi. I need a query to display the customer service flow with a count in sql query.

I need a idea to implement the concept like this

| column1 | column2 | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| language | mainmenu | 170 |
| mainmenu | exit | 15 |
| mainmenu | customer service | 155 |
| customer service | connected | 140 |
| customer service | exit | 15 |

this is was my sample data i have this in pivot format i want to know how to build this logic in SQL

Comment: can you show your expected with text

Comment: You should add how your original data looks too

Comment: actually i want to express the flow in sankey chart in powerbi , now i am having only excel data . i want a sql query to satisfy the logic like capturing the flow of customer service calls,,     like  one person entering the customer service and selecting the language menu and then selecting the option in main menu then exit the call. this is the flow i am having in table so i want to track this flow in sql  by using cross apply or unpivot

Answer (score 0):

It could be better if you provided an example of your pivoted data. If it looks like my example in #temp table, you can use unpivoting function.

```
create table #temp(column1 varchar(255), [mainmenu] int, [customer service] int, [connected] int, [exit] int)

insert into #temp
values
('language',170,0,0,0),
('mainmenu',0,155,0,15),
('customer service',0,0,140,15)
```

[image]

```
select column1, column2, [count]
from (
    select column1,[mainmenu],[customer service],[connected],[exit]
    from #temp
) as pvt
unpivot(
    [count] for column2 in ([mainmenu],[customer service],[connected],[exit])
) as unpvt
where [count] <> 0 --it's for removing zero values in the output
```

[[image]